# Python conditional vlookup?

Tags: python-3.x

Im using pandas dataframes to work with 2 csv files
I need a vlookup, but I want to apply another vlookup if the result is a null string....any idea?

one dataframe file is called  `data`
the other is called           `data2`

this vlookup (WORKING code), will find `data["ID A"]  == data2['Person_ID']` and bring `data2 ['Status_job']` from that row:

Code:

`data['STATUS X'] = data['ID A'].map ( data2[['Person_ID', 'Status_job']].set_index('Person_ID') ['Status_job'].to_dict()   )`

BUT, I want another vlookup in case that `['Status_job']` return a null string. (same code but `Program_ID` instead `Person_ID`)

Working code2:
`data['STATUS X'] = data['ID A'].map ( data2[['Program_ID', 'Status_job']].set_index('Program_ID') ['Status_job'].to_dict()   )`

How can I merge these 2 codes into 1 conditional? tried `.loc` and `lambda x`, but not sure how to make it work with no error, will appreciate any help.